# Finding SQL Days between two dates with nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns: `rental_date` and `actual_retdate`. I need to find the amount of days between the `actual_retdate` and `rental_date`. The `actual_retdate` can be null for some instances so I would like to find the amount of days between today's date and the rental date in those situations.

Currently I have:

```
select rental_date, actual_retdate, actual_retdate - rental_date as 'Daysbetween' 
from rental_agreement
```

This gives me answers of:

```
Rental_date     actual_retdate  Daysbetween
2014-07-04  2014-07-11  7
2016-05-06  2016-05-08  2
2016-08-07  2016-09-07  100
2015-02-02  2015-02-10  8
2015-10-10  2015-10-15  5
2015-08-07  2015-08-17  10
2017-02-04  NULL            NULL
2016-07-08  2016-07-16  8
2017-03-02  NULL            NULL
2015-03-15  2015-04-15  100
```

Comment: In MySQL, the subtraction operator isn't guaranteed to return a number days between two date values. It may work in some cases (when the two dates are in the same year and month), but doesn't return a correct value in the more general case. (Note the rows with a return of `100`. In MySQL, we can get a difference in days using `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,dateexpr1,dateexpr2)`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you could coalesce the actual_retdate with NOW().

It would look something like:

```
SELECT rental_date, 
    actual_retdate, 
    COALESCE(actual_retdate,NOW()) - rental_date as 'Daysbetween' 
FROM rental_agreement
```

COALESCE basically returns the first non-null value in the list. So if actual_retdate is NULL, it will return the value for NOW().

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

---

Edit: Since Spencer mentioned subtraction not being completely reliable as a way to get the difference in number of days, here's an updated snippet using his suggested TIMESTAMPDIFF.

```
SELECT rental_date, 
    actual_retdate, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,COALESCE(actual_retdate,NOW()),rental_date) as 'Daysbetween' 
FROM rental_agreement
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE` to provide another value for the case when a value is `NULL`:

```
SELECT
    rental_date,
    actual_retdate
    COALESCE( actual_retdate, CURDATE() ) AS actual_retdate_or_today,
    COALESCE( actual_retdate, CURDATE() ) - rental_date AS days_between
FROM
    rental_agreement
```

`CURDATE()` returns the current date. I assume that `actual_retdate` is a `date` column rather than a `datetime` column, as the results may be unexpected. Also consider using `DATEADD` instead of the `-` operator for performing date-arithmetic calculations.

The reason I repeated the `COALESCE( actual_retdate, CURDATE() )` expression is because in SQL you cannot reference a column expression in another column - you must either recompute the result or wrap it in an outer-query.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `coalesce()`:

```
select rental_date, actual_retdate,
       coalesce(actual_retdate, curdate()) - rental_date as Daysbetween 
from rental_agreement
```